# Animate multiple sequences of images side by side

Tags: beamer, graphics, animations

Say I have 2 sequences of images `imA-1.png`,`imA-2.png`,...,`imA-n.png` and `imB-1.png`,...`imB-n.png` . I would like to use something like `xmpmulti`'s `\multiinclude`, but the following prints the `imA` sequence alone and then `imA-n.png` side by side with the entire `imB` sequence:

```
\begin{frame}

\multiinclude[format=png,start=1,graphics={width=0.4\textwidth}]{imA}
\multiinclude[format=png,start=1,graphics={width=0.4\textwidth}]{imB}

\end{frame}
```

Any suggestions for how to get `imA-1.png` with `imB-1.png`, `imA-2.png` with `imB-2.png`, and so forth?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get right what you want to do, you should try to use `\animategraphics`, which is in the `animate` package. It works simply like that, for your problem

```
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \animategraphics[autoplay, width=1.\textwidth]{3}{imA-}{1}{n}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \animategraphics[autoplay, width=1.\textwidth]{3}{imB-}{1}{n}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

You pass some arguments in the brackets (`autoplay` to have it starting automatically, you can use `loop` to have it looping etc.), the second argument is the number of frames per second (here it is 3), then it is the "root" of the name of your images, and finally the starting and ending indices.

Comment: Thanks! Who knew PDFs could do this? Cool! Is Adobe Reader the only software that handles this fully? That could be a problem for hopping on someone else's machine to give a presentation.

Comment: As far as I know this kind of features works only with Adobe reader unfortunately. I think that the only way to have a "cross-reader" way to display animations is to put an hyperlink that opens a media player.