# Putting side by side animations in beamer

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I am using the `animate` package with `beamer` in order to create animations within a presentation of mine.  So far I have no trouble doing it with one series of animations, but I wanted to know is there a way to have two animations side-by-side that works off of a single (I don't know what you call it) "play button"?  I want to be able to hit play and watch both animations go at the same time (and all other buttons similarly).

Here is an example of the code for the slide I am using currently:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Solution}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\animategraphics[controls,loop,scale=0.33]{10}{plot}{1}{47}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129618/animate-multiple-sequences-of-images-side-by-side) allows me to put the animations side-by-side, however, I don't know how to make it have a single play button.

Here is the solution using the side-by-side solution in [Animate multiple sequences of images side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129618/animate-multiple-sequences-of-images-side-by-side)

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Solution}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \animategraphics[controls,loop,scale=0.33]{10}{plot}{1}{47}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \animategraphics[controls,loop,scale=0.33]{10}{plot}{1}{47}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `animate` package provides a [programming interface](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#page=14), which could be used for this purpose.

For example, a common play/pause button could be inserted with:

```
...

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9} %for \mediabutton

...

\animategraphics[label=animA,controls,loop,scale=0.33]{10}{plot}{1}{47}
\animategraphics[label=animB,controls,loop,scale=0.33]{10}{plot}{1}{47}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    if(anim.animA.isPlaying) anim.animA.pause();
    else anim.animA.playFwd();
    if(anim.animB.isPlaying) anim.animB.pause();
    else anim.animB.playFwd();
  }
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}

...
```