# how to put 4 animations next to each other in a presentation?

Tags: beamer, columns, animations

I am creating a presentation in Latex where I have 2 slides which would contain 4-4 slides in a window-like setup. I found this link: [Add four images on a beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74903/add-four-images-on-a-beamer-frame) and tried to put the animations like that but it does not work with animations. It ends up like this no matter what:

[image]

However, I would like to put them like in the link. Like this:

[image]

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\animategraphics[autoplay, loop,scale=0.33]{25}{gif/frame-}{0}{36}\\
\animategraphics[autoplay, loop,scale=0.33]{25}{gif/frame-}{0}{36}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\animategraphics[autoplay, loop,scale=0.33]{25}{gif/frame-}{0}{36}\\
\animategraphics[autoplay, loop,scale=0.33]{25}{gif/frame-}{0}{36}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also tried this with animate: [how can I put multiple video next to each other on one slide presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480925/how-can-i-put-multiple-video-next-to-each-other-on-one-slide-presentation?rq=1) but it does not change anything regarding the animations.

Edit:
Based on this answer from '13: [Animate multiple sequences of images side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129618/animate-multiple-sequences-of-images-side-by-side), it seems like it worked previously but something has changed.

Edit: `\begin{columns}[b]` or `\begin{columns}[c]` or `\begin{columns}[t]` or `\begin{columns}[T]` with and without `\centering` did not change anything. Neither if I put any of them after `\begin{frame}`.

Edit: The inputs are in png format. Using `height` and `width` explicilty changes the size of the animations but no the location.

Edit: Something really weird is happening since even I just put one animation in the slide, it will be placed in the lower left corner.

Edit: `\begin{center}` does the same as the first try. It does not change anything.

Edit: Creating a fully new version with just one slide, it works as expected. Not sure what happens in my actual project which makes it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Ok. Will try to create something.

Comment: I am not sure why this is, but you can maybe place the animations in `minipage`s or `\parbox`es and this way specify the height and width.

Comment: I did try the minipages approach but the animation was out of them.

Comment: I think that the correct syntax for the columns should be `\begin{columns} \column{0.5\textwidth} ... \column{0.5\textwidth}... \end{columns}`

Comment: Have you try `\begin{columns}[b]` or `\begin{columns}[c]` or `\begin{columns}[t]` or `\begin{columns}[T]` with and without `\centering`?

Comment: Neither of the combination changed anything.

Comment: You could also try to set explicitly `width` and `height` for `\animategraphics`.

Comment: And what about `\begin{frame}[b]` or `\begin{frame}[c]` or `\begin{frame}[t]`?

Comment: If I use `example-movie.pdf` from pkg `mwe` with your code, the output looks as expected. What happens if you place `\includegraphics[scale=0.33]{gif/frame-0}` in the columns?

Comment: You can try to place the animations without the columns as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430213/162128).

Comment: Yes, moreover those beamer columns are weird: two of them with `0.5\textwidth` placed side-by-side are wider than the normal text area of `\textwidth`, without a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[%physical paper width=8in, physical paper height=6in]
```

lines caused the whole problem. Removing them fixed the issue.